# jQuery Ajax request - Update DIV element on content change

Tags: jquery, ajax

I´m not sure if i did my ajax query architecture on the right way.

Actually i query my results in the PHP, the Ajax is requesting.
The output is the hole div-table which is .append() to the DIV with the ID "stored_entries".
I think it´s the best way for performance - rather than making a request for each row, right?

Now i want to make a visual effect - when Paul switched to "online" - on the updated rows (item1, ...).

```
<div id="stored_entries">
  <div id="item_<?php echo $item_ID;?>">
    <div id="ID">1</div>
    <div id="NAME">Paul</div>
    <div id="ONLINE">Online</div>
  </div>
  <div id="item_<?php echo $item_ID;?>">
    <div id="ID">2</div>
    <div id="NAME">Peter</div>
    <div id="ONLINE">Offline</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought about to use jQuery to detect which row content changed, but i´m not getting on the right track.

Do i need to add the jQuery to the PHP requested file or do i need to add it to the `.complete()` / `.success()` function?

I found something like this but i´m not sure who to use it.

```
$(document).on('contentchanged', '#item_<?php echo $item_ID;?>', function() {
  // do something after the div content has changed
  alert('WOO?');
});

jQuery("#item_<?php echo $item_ID; ?>").trigger('contentchanged');
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: where is triggered #item_ id is not available. 

 jQuery("#item_").trigger('contentchanged');

Comment: Was just the formatting. That´s not the Problem.

Comment: I am not sure when is triggered "contentchanged" ? What is exact issue ?

Comment: I need to do an action on the row which has a change on the content. So, if status goes from offline to online i want to make a visual effect on that row. The code is just an idea. i just need to get an idea how i could realize that.